# read and filter text file then write last 10 results to page

Tags: php

I have a script that reads a text log file, looks for lines that contain the word "name" and then outputs the results to a page.

Log file contains many different things. Snapshot of the log is below:

```
10.07.2021 19:25:10: Peter-L: TCP heartbeat timeout
10.07.2021 19:25:14: Client 123.45.7.9:37000 connected
10.07.2021 19:25:14: Peter-L: Already connected
10.07.2021 19:25:14: Client 123.45.7.9:37000 disconnected: Connection closed by remote peer
10.07.2021 19:25:19: Peter-L: disconnected: Connection closed by remote peer
10.07.2021 19:25:20: Client 123.45.7.9:37000 connected
10.07.2021 19:25:20: Peter-L: Login OK from 123.45.7.9:37000 with protocol version 2.0
10.07.2021 19:25:20: Peter-L: Monitor TG#: [ 91 214 235 505 ]
10.07.2021 19:25:21: ### ReflectorClient::handleStateEvent: src=TetraLogic name=Sds:info msg=[{"last_activity":"1625909121","source":"Gateway2","tsi":"0022352","type":12}]
10.07.2021 19:26:43: ### ReflectorClient::handleStateEvent: src=TetraLogic name=QsoInfo:state msg=[{"call":"Steve-1","last_activity":"1625908748","source":"Gateway1","tsi":"0011223"}]
```

I'm only interested in the following line within the log:

```
10.07.2021 19:26:43: ### ReflectorClient::handleStateEvent: src=TetraLogic name=QsoInfo:state msg=[{"call":"Steve-1","last_activity":"1625908748","source":"Gateway1","tsi":"0011223"}]
```

When this line appears in the log (it appears multiple times within the log), i'd like to grab the following from that line in the log and post it to the page. There would be many results within the log, so i'd like to filter the output to only show the last 10 entries.

```
Date (10.07.2021) | Time (19:26:43) | Name (Steve-1)
```

Script so far:

```
<?php
$lines = array();
$fopen = fopen('logfile.log', 'r');
while (!feof($fopen)) {
    $line=fgets($fopen);
    $line=trim($line);
    $lines[]=$line;

}
fclose($fopen);
$finalOutput = array();
foreach ($lines as $string)
{
       if (stripos(strtolower($string), 'name') !== false) {
                $row = explode(" ", $string);
                array_push($finalOutput,$row);
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($finalOutput);
                echo "</pre>";
       }
```

Right now my output looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10.07.2021
            [1] => 03:44:21:
            [2] => ###
            [3] => ReflectorClient::handleStateEvent:
            [4] => src=SuperLogic
            [5] => name=QsoInfo:state
            [6] => msg=[{"call":"Steve-1","last_activity":"1625852661","source":"gateway1","tsi":"0011223"}]
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10.07.2021
            [1] => 03:44:21:
            [2] => ###
            [3] => ReflectorClient::handleStateEvent:
            [4] => src=SuperLogic
            [5] => name=QsoInfo:state
            [6] => msg=[{"call":"Steve-1","last_activity":"1625852661","source":"gateway1","tsi":"0011223"}]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10.07.2021
            [1] => 13:20:26:
            [2] => ###
            [3] => ReflectorClient::handleStateEvent:
            [4] => src=SuperLogic
            [5] => name=QsoInfo:state
            [6] => msg=[{"call":"James-2","last_activity":"1625887226","source":"gateway2","tsi":"0011244"}]
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10.07.2021
            [1] => 03:44:21:
            [2] => ###
            [3] => ReflectorClient::handleStateEvent:
            [4] => src=SuperLogic
            [5] => name=QsoInfo:state
            [6] => msg=[{"call":"Steve-1","last_activity":"1625852661","source":"gateway1","tsi":"0011223"}]
        )
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add an example of what the input file looks like and what the output from that example should be.

Comment: Many thanks! I've updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

To sort only the 10 last result you can use array_slice :

```
    $lines= array_slice($lines, -10) ;
    // return the 10 last lines of an array
```

About the output, "msg" is a json string, I suggest remove `"msg["` and `]` then json_decode the string :

```
$jsonResult = str_replace("msg[", "", $row[6]);
$jsonResult = str_replace("]", "", $jsonResult);
$jsonResult = json_decode($jsonResult) ;
```

So you can use and call `$jsonResult->call` and `$jsonResult->tsi`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Where would I slot $lines= array_slice($lines, -10) ; in?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my final code im using. It's messy, but it does seem to work:

```
 <?php
    $i = 0;
    $lines=array();   

$fopen = fopen('logfile.log', 'r');
    while (!feof($fopen)) {

    $line = fgets($fopen, 4096);
        array_push($lines, $line);
    }
rsort($lines);
    fclose($fopen);
    


    foreach ($lines as $string)
    {
           if (stripos(strtolower($string), 'name=QsoInfo') !== false) {
        $string = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $string);
            $row = explode(" ", $string);
               array_push($finalOutput,$row);
    

        $pieces = explode(" ", $string);
        $i++;

        echo "<tr bgcolor=e6edf2><td height=20>";
        
        echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
        echo "</td></tr>";          
         
        }
        
    if ($i == 10) break;
     }
       
?>
```